# MQTT client disconnects from Watson IoT platform: "The topic is not valid: temp The topic does not match an authorized rule"

Tags: watson-iot

I'm using the Node-RED MQTT client to send an event to the Watson IoT platform. The client connects successfully. However, when I inject the payload and send it to the platform the clients gets disconnected immediately and re-connects after some time.

**Connection log:** 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disconnects usually happens when the topic is invalid (you should use the format `iot-2/evt/[event id]/fmt/json`) or the payload is invalid (standard json format such as `{ "myvariable": 0 }`, remember of using double quotes in variable names).

Does this helps ?

Comment: nice! which was the problem ?